# libxml2 output namespace declarations in non-root elements

Tags: xml, libxml2

I have a document like this

```
<a:root xmlns:a="http://example.com/roots" xmlns:b="http://example.com/subs" xmlns:c="http://example.com/subsubs">
    <b:sub>
        <c:subsub>Hello World</c:subsub>
    </b:sub>
</a:root>
```

Using xmlNodeDump I want to output XML for *sub* and deeper only i.e. I want to end up with

```
<b:sub xmlns:b="http://example.com/subs" xmlns:c="http://example.com/subsubs">
    <c:subsub>Hellow World<c:subsub>
</b:sub>
```

However because the namespace declarations are in the *root* tag, when I dump the XML, the namespace declarations are lost and I end up with

```
<b:sub>
    <c:subsub>Hellow World<c:subsub>
</b:sub>
```

Which is not valid anymore. The question is: How can I make sure the XML being output has the relevant namespace declarations added to the new top-level element i.e. to *sub* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to copy the node before dumping it:

```
xmlNodePtr copy = xmlCopyNode(node, 1);
xmlNodeDump(..., copy, ...);
xmlFreeNode(copy);
```

`xmlCopyNode` adds the necessary namespace declarations to the copied node.

Comment: Sir, you are a champion.